# VS 2010 Major Publish Version Change - New Application or Overwrite Previous Version

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, clickonce

Using Visual Studio 2010 Professional Windows Form App. Currently a ClickOnce application has only been incrementing the Revision value (1.0.0.15). Settings are to Automatically increment revision with each publish. Client app updates automatically before application opens.

If I manually increment the Major value (2.0.0.0), is this going to install another version of the application or just overwrite/update the existing version on a client's machine? I recall using the express version and this happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the minimum version in the Updates dialog, or your application is online only, ClickOnce only keeps one version on the client machine.

If you are not pushing the update as required (minimum version is filled in), and your application is online/offline, ClickOnce keeps two versions on the client machine. This means that the user can go to Add/RemovePrograms and back out the most recent version if needed.

ClickOnce installs whatever version number is in the deployment manifest (.application file) in the root folder of the deployment folders. If you change your version to 2.0 and deploy it, it will install 2.0. If you then decide you don't like it and want to go back, you can pull an earlier version of the .application file out of one of the Application Files folders and copy it to the root folder, and the next time the user runs the application, it will install that version. This doesn't work if you are pushing updates as required (min version).

If you want to run multiple versions of the same application on the same machine, you have to change the assembly name, the product name, the publishing folder location, and the installation URL.

Answer (score 2):

Incrementing any part of the version number **will not** install another version of the application.  It will simply update the existing installation.